# CS Cart 4.0.2: how to get tax name or value in product page template?

Tags: templates, cs-cart

How could I know the product tax (its amount and/or its name) in the product page template of CS Cart 4.0.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$order_info = fn_get_order_info($_REQUEST['order_id']);
var_dump($order_info);
```

then you can see the whole array and look for tax_id.

Comment: what order are you talking about?